# Print UTF8 characets to windows console using a source file with a UTF8 encoding

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8

i'm trying to print a UTF8 character like `ê` to the Windows Console with a c++ console application, i'm using `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` and i'm getting the result like expected, but, my source file needs to have the following encoding: UTF8 without Signature, yeah that's necessary because i'm getting the UTF8 Hex value of a string, so my problem is, how to print to the console a character like `ê` with a source file like that and not print what i am getting (Ãª)

Comment: Tell your text editor to save the file encoded in utf8 with a BOM.  The BOM is important, that is how the compiler knows that the source file contains utf8 encoded text.  There might also be a compile option to tell it that.  Not telling us anything about the tooling you use makes it hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

With [u8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) you can specify that a string is always encoded as UTF8, regardless of the source file's actual encoding.

Comment: how can i use u8 with a string variable? and not a string literal

Comment: when you put utf8-content into a string, there will be utf8 within the string. What do you mean with 'using with a string variable'?

Comment: if i do that i will have one more problem that is: the output when i use ToHex("ê") is `EA` and not `C3 AA` just like i want do you understand? i need to set source file to utf8 encoding because of that

Comment: Yes, but you still have to correctly tell the compiler what the source encoding is.